# Redirect to wordpress blog through nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, location

I am new to both, the nginx and the wordpress.
I have configured my project to be served through the nginx server. Now we need to add the wordpress blog support to our project.
My nginx is running over port 80. And the Apache is running over 8181 where my wordpress is installed.

Now any url going to blog is redirected to the apache over 8181 through my nginx server.

So below is my nginx redirect for the blog urls.

```
location /blog {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181/blog/;
            proxy_redirect https://192.168.1.54 http://127.0.0.1:8181/blog;

            proxy_read_timeout       3500;
            proxy_connect_timeout    3250;

            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  https;

            proxy_set_header   SSL_PROTOCOL $ssl_protocol;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_cert;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
            proxy_set_header   SSL_SERVER_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
        }
```

For the Google page speed insight, I did below config.

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
```

Now, the problem I am facing here is that, when some css or js request comes from the wordpress eg. *http://192.168.1.54/blog/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css?ver=4.6* is getting caught inside the location config written for css ie. **location ~* .(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff)$** Hence wordpress is not able to get the css or js.

So, I need your help where the any URL requested for **blog** on the nginx should be redirected to Apache server on 8181 port. Including the js and css.
Where as other resource related url like https://192.168.1.54/js/somejs.js should also work.

I did some config change in wordpress file **wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://192.168.1.54/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://192.168.1.54/blog');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `^~` modifier on the `location /blog` block to prevent conflict with regular expression location blocks at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

```
location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
    ...
}
```

Also, you should probably remove the URL element from the `proxy_pass` directive, because it looks like you are mapping `/blog` to `/blog` anyway.

And the `proxy_redirect` statement is back to front. But you probably do not need it as you have set WP_HOME/WP_SITEURL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard. This has stopped my blog url redirection to the blog again.
But my main problem still exists. The wordpress css and js are still showing 404. Some how I still need to do something with the block location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff)$. If I remove this block then the css and js are loaded for wordpress. But not with this block.

Comment: There must be a problem elsewhere in your configuration file, because `location ~*` cannot override `location ^~` - see the documentation I referenced in my answer.